# Continuous Opacity change in Background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was working on a website and I wanted to know how exactly does the continuous change in the opacity happen , in the background...

Here's the link:
I want it to work like this http://www.cecchi.net/  ~

Guy's I used css animation.. and the keyframe thingy kind of works , but the problem is I don't know how to randomly assign the opacity to each divisions.. Here's the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  .div1,
    div2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    /* Standard syntax */
    
    @keyframes example {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0.3;
      }
      60% {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .div1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }
    }
    
    .div2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      animation-name: example;
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="div1"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="div2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're looking for CSS animations.

Comment: @Tried it... But I;m facing difficulties. Sorry I'm a newbie at this.. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly, but you'll have to assign id's to a grid of divs that overlay your picture, then using javascript/jQuery run a function that randomly changes opacity and filters for each of the divs. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its is barba.js click the link below:

> https://github.com/luruke/barba.js/

there are lots of transitions you can find on above link...